# If statement for key press with 'GetAsyncKeyState' runs one after another

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, c++20

I am running a `while` loop in which the program is listening for specific keys, like pressing <kbd>Q</kbd> once should start a process, pressing <kbd>Q</kbd> again should stop it, and pressing <kbd>E</kbd> should break the loop.

The code I am using to achieve this is:

```cpp
input.type = INPUT_MOUSE;

while (true) {
    if (printed_1 != true) {
        cout << "Autoclicker Running" << endl;
        printed_1 = true;
    }

    if (GetAsyncKeyState('Q') && started == false) {
        if (printed_2 != true) {
            cout << "Autoclicker Started" << endl;
            printed_2 = true;
        }
        printed_3 = false;

        click = true;
        started = true;
    }

    if (GetAsyncKeyState('Q') && started == true) {
        if (printed_3 != true) {
            cout << "Autoclicker Stopped" << endl;
            printed_3 = true;
        }
        printed_2 = false;

        click = false;
        started = false;
    }

    if (GetAsyncKeyState('E') && !exit_key_down) {
        cout << "Exiting Program" << endl;
        click = false;
        break;
    }

    if (click == true) {
        if (get<0>(button) == 1) {
            input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;
            
        } else if (get<0>(button) == 2) {
            input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN;
            
        } else if (get<0>(button) == 4) {
            input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEDOWN;
        }
        SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(INPUT));

        if (get<0>(button) == 1) {
            input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;
            
        } else if (get<0>(button) == 2) {
            input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP;
            
        } else if (get<0>(button) == 4) {
            input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEUP;
        }
        SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(INPUT));

        Sleep(1);
    }
}
```

When this code is run, I press <kbd>Q</kbd> and the first `if` statments runs, but what shouldn't happen is that the second `if` statements also runs right after, stopping the process. Pressing <kbd>E</kbd> works no matter what.

Output when this code is run is:

<kbd>Q</kbd> is pressed once:

```
Autoclicker Started
Autoclicker Stopped
```

<kbd>E</kbd>is pressed once:

```
Exiting Program
```

I have tried adding other boolean values to make the `if` statement  more accurate. Like adding `bool toggle_key_down = false` to the first two `if` statements, like so:

```cpp
if (GetAsyncKeyState('Q') && toggle_key_down == false && started == false) {
    if (printed_2 != true) {
        cout << "Autoclicker Started" << endl;
        printed_2 = true;
    }
    printed_3 = false
    click = true;
    started = true;
    toggle_key_down = true;
}
if (GetAsyncKeyState('Q') && toggle_key_down == true && started == false) {
    if (printed_2 != true) {
        cout << "Autoclicker Started" << endl;
        printed_2 = true;
    }
    printed_3 = false
    click = true;
    started = true;
    toggle_key_down = false;
}
```

I have also tried adding a delay between the `if` statements, thinking that maybe it was due to the program processing one key press for both `if` statements, like so:

```cpp
if (GetAsyncKeyState('Q') && toggle_key_down == false && started == false) {
    if (printed_2 != true) {
        cout << "Autoclicker Started" << endl;
        printed_2 = true;
    }
    printed_3 = false
    click = true;
    started = true;
    toggle_key_down = true;
}
Sleep(0.1);
if (GetAsyncKeyState('Q') && toggle_key_down == true && started == false) {
    if (printed_2 != true) {
        cout << "Autoclicker Started" << endl;
        printed_2 = true;
    }
    printed_3 = false
    click = true;
    started = true;
    toggle_key_down = false;
}
```

I have made sure that all the proper libraries are included, but the output is the same.

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: The simplest solution would be to use a different key for starting and stopping. Otherwise you'll need to check for the key being released before accepting another key press

Comment: Instead of `GetAsyncKeyState()`, comsider using `ReadConsoleInput()` or `SetWindowsHookEx()` to get separate down/up events for each key stroke.